# is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onclick

Tags: javascript

Just to start out I've already looked on here for similar issues but none of those really put me in the right direction. Anyways, i'm having an issue where when I click an object on my login it doesn't send the function `selectPlayer` which I provided the code below.

```
function RenderFullAvatarCards(LoginData) 
{
      var avatarNumber = 0;
      $("#externalSystem").html('<center><div id="avatarCards" class="clickCard" style="margin-top:30px;"></div><br><div class="shadow"></div><div class="login-different" id="changePenguin">Change Penguin</div></center>');
    for (var i in LoginData['Accounts']) {
        $("#avatarCards").append('<div id="avatarCard_' + avatarNumber + '"  onclick="selectPlayer(' + i + ', ' + avatarNumber + ');" class="playerSelect"><div id="penguin" style="background:url(//localhost/play/assets/img/doll.png) no-repeat;position:relative;top:66px;width:144px;height:250px;"></div><span id="penguinName">' + LoginData['Accounts'][i][0] + '</span></div>');
        avatarNumber++;
    };
    $("#changePenguin").on('click', function() {
        renderNewPlayer(true);
    });
}
```

The actual error I receive is this

```
(index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Reed is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick ((index):1)
```

which refers to the top of my index as it starts with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Any ideas what could possibly be the issue?

Comment: I think...That's mean "onclick" property is not available in "div" tag. Try other.

Comment: Where is the code of `selectPlayer`? You're refering to it in an inline onclick attribute `onclick="selectPlayer(...);"`, so it must be defined somewhere.

Comment: What is `LoginData['Accounts']`? If it's an object with non-numeric keys, then the issue is you aren't quoting `i` in `'selectPlayer(' + i + ', ' + avatarNumber + ')'`

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir The selectPlayer isn't needed cause all it does brings up the login page for the selected user. @Phil It stores the saved accounts `localStorage`

Comment: The error happens in a click event listener. The code you post contains two. You provided the code to one which doesn't contain the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess (and I do because you haven't provided enough information), your `LoginData` object looks something like

```
{
  Accounts: {
    Reed: ['Happy Feet']
  }
}
```

The issue here is that because `i` will be the value "Reed", your inline `onclick` attribute will look something like

```
onclick="selectPlayer(Reed, 0)"
```

Because `Reed` isn't quoted, JavaScript is looking for a variable of that name, hence...

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Reed is not defined

Quick and dirty solution... add quotes

```
onclick="selectPlayer(\'' + i + '\', ' + avatarNumber + ')
```

---

A much better solution would be to add some data / attributes to your element and use a delegated event listener to handle the clicks. For example

```
$(document).on('click', '.playerSelect', function() {
  let player = $(this)
  selectPlayer(player.data('account'), player.data('avatar-number'))
})
```

and in your `RenderFullAvatarCards` function...

```
var avatarCards = Object.keys(LoginData.Accounts).map((account, avatarNumber) => {
  return $('<div></div>')
    .attr('id', 'avatarCard_' + avatarNumber)
    .data('account', account)
    .data('avatar-number', avatarNumber)
    .addClass('playerSelect')
    .append(...) // add span elements, etc
})
$("#avatarCards").append(avatarCards)
```

Comment: ```LoginData = {
                'AccountNumber': 0,
                'Accounts': {}
            }``` but yeah thanks it worked! Is there a cleaner method?